# Один и тот же background для header и следующей section

Tags: css

Задача: для  header и секции, следующей за ним, нужно задать один  background. Position:absolute; для header ситуацию не исправил.background получается задать либо header, либо section. Как задать 1 и тот же фон двум элементам ?

```
<header>

    <div class="logo">
            <a href="#">Transitive<span>by templated</span></a>
        </div>

    <section id="banner">
        <h1>Transitive</h1>
            <p>A full responsive, business-oriented HTML5/CSS3 template</p> <br>
            <p>built by <a href="#">templated</a>and released under the <a 
            href="#">Creative Commons</a>
            </p>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

А в чём проблема включить section в header и задать фон только header'у? Тогда он будет единым.

Если по какой-то причине этого сделать нельзя, просто оберните header и section общим div'ом и задайте фон этому диву.

Comment: Насколько знаю, header  по иерархии элементов должен идти первым и оборачивать его во что-то - неправильно. Исправьте меня, если я не права

Comment: @Кристина, я знаю, что header нельзя помещать внутрь элементов footer, address или другого элемента header. Про то, что его в принципе нельзя ничем оборачивать, впервые слышу, если честно. Дайте ссылку, где такое написано

Comment: header можно совать куда угодно. И не раз. Да, это будет неверно семантически, но работать от этого не перестанет.

Comment: @Инквизитор, ну так-то всё что угодно можно совать куда угодно, и работать не перестанет. HTML в принципе не может не работать (это ж не язык программирования). Но мы именно семантику и валидность разметки обсуждаем.

Comment: вообще-то мы обсуждаем наследование стилей, а не валидность разметки.
И, да, абсолютно никто не запрещает оборачивать хедер во что-нибудь еще - главное, чтобы тип элемента соотетствовал назначению.

Comment: @Инквизитор, причём здесь наследование? :)) Вопрос в том, как сделать единый фон для двух соседних элементов

Comment: @humster_spb, вообще-то, если внимательно прочесть вопрос автора, то можно сделать вывод, что он не знает, как задать один фон а) некоему элементу и б) следующему за ним (по какой-то причине ему непосредственно задать не удается) одновременно. Другого вывода без дополнительной информации сделать не получается. "Интуитивно я, конечно, догадываюсь", что, возможно, речь идет о совмещении фонов хедера и секции так, чтобы выглядело едино, но из постановки задачи это не следует никак.

Comment: @Инквизитор, и что? Наследование-то тут при чём? :) Не надо умничать ))

Comment: @humster_spb, неверно, сталбыть выразился. Не "наследование", а "применение стиля к элементу, СЛЕДУЮЩЕМУ за указанным в селекторе". Так понятнее?

Answer (score 0):

```
header ~ section {background-color:red;}
```

Позиционирование тут абсолютно не при чем.

Comment: Обычный цвет, как я понимаю, тоже не при чем. Там, видимо, проблема с background-image: картинка должна быть одним фоном для двух элементов.

Answer (score 0):

Ну а если использовать наследование?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: url(https://im0-tub-kz.yandex.net/i?id=989a846708cb140a2493643d20e8abaf-l&n=13);
  background-size: 0;
}

header,
section {
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<section></section>
```